# PLESK - No access to Backup Manager

Tags: plesk

On the frontend of the plesk when I go to "Tools" > "Backupmanager" the page loads some **minutes** and then it times just out. 
On the server via ssh I saw, that the process pmmcli get one more entry for one call of the backupmanager-page. Even killing the process is not going to work except the timeout comes faster. And the pmmcli - process is keeping the machine quite busy after a few tries.

My question is, how I can get the backup manager up running again?

I am still a rookie with server and even more (or less?) with plesk. I beg for your help or some tips please :)

Comment: You may want to check /usr/local/psa/admin/logs/panel.log and logs in /usr/local/psa/PMM/logs/